# How to name JFrame in a constructor

Tags: java, swing, variables, jframe

Question may be different than what you expected, but I'm creating a utility function for JFrames to make it easier for future me.

```
public void setJframe(String title, int w,int h, JFrame name, Boolean maximize){
    name.setSize(w, h);
    name.setTitle(title);

    if (maximize == true) {
        name.setExtendedState(name.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    } else {
        name.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

I want the ability to name the JFrame as I type in the parameters. At the moment, when I type in a string it simply spits out an error saying I can't use a string? I want "name" to be like a string variable where I can type in a string value and have the object be named that.

**Edit:** Need to make the question more clear...

```
PackageName.setJframe("Title of the Frame", 500, 800, f, false);
```

Returns this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
>
> > f cannot be resolved
> >
> > f cannot be resolved
> >
> > > at gui.GuiMain.guiSet(GuiMain.java:17)
> > >
> > > at urAPackage.Main.main(Main.java:8)

Eclipse says method f is not applicable to constructor

Comment: 1. Your question makes no sense. 2. Your if statement is using an _assignment_ operator, not a _comparison_.

Comment: You need to show the code that causes the error, indicate which line it is, and show the full error message. Otherwise I have no idea what you're trying to do or what is not working.

Comment: Well, where do you declare `f`?

Comment: Exactly as @peeskillet states -- the compiler error message isn't cryptic -- it states that you seem to be trying to use a JFrame variable that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your method, `setJframe`, you simply need to pass an instantiated new JFrame into the forth parameter as such:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CreateJFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
                    setJframe("Title of the first Frame", 500, 800, frame1, false);
                    frame1.setVisible(true);

                    JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
                    setJframe("Title of the second Frame", 100, 200, frame2, false);
                    frame2.setVisible(true);

                    JFrame frame3 = new JFrame();
                    setJframe("Title of the third Frame", 100, 200, frame3, true);
                    frame3.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void setJframe(String title, int w, int h, JFrame name, Boolean maximize) {
        name.setSize(w, h);
        name.setTitle(title);

        if (maximize == true) {
            name.setExtendedState(name.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        } else {
            name.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want the forth parameter to be a string, you could either extend a JFrame and specify your additional constructor(s) to accept the string, or you can create a method whereby a JFrame object is returned.

EDIT: Unless of course, you meant naming the internal variable name. This functionality is not possible during runtime. I can't imagine any use for such a function anyways. The above paragraph assumes you mean setting the name of a JFrame (via `setName()`).

Comment: Thank you! My friend ultimately led me to this but you understood the question so props to you!

Answer (score 0):

Variable names are only known at compile time. You cannot create a variable name from the value of a String at run time.

Comment: So is it possible to name the created JFrame as a parameter? Any other methods?

Comment: @MasterWhipper You already named the JFrame as `name`. You can change this to any valid variable name that you want.