# How does the implementation of this bitwise operator make sense?

Tags: java, swing, operators, bit-manipulation

In an earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23975528/230513) regarding how to maximize the JFrame I saw this bit of code and it worked. I took out the

```
name.getExtendedState()
```

and it still worked? What does the use of the "getter" and the OR symbol accomplish?

```
name.setExtendedState(name.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `name.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH` means that you're *adding* `MAXIMIZED_BOTH` to the existing extended state. If you say *only* `JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH`, that means you're *replacing* the extended state with only that bit, and throwing away anything in the current extended state.

Comment: But it's not needed though right? I took it out and everything is just fine and dandy. Seems like bloat to me.

Comment: In this specific instance (and _only_ in this specific instance), where you're setting `MAXIMIZED_BOTH`, you can safely clear out the other bits, because the only other bit there is is `ICONIFIED`, and it doesn't make sense to set that alongsite `MAXIMIZED_BOTH`. But, if, say, you're actually trying to set `MAXIMIZED_HORIZ`, and `MAXIMIZED_VERT` is already set, then your approach will inadvertently clear `MAXIMIZED_VERT`, perhaps to the user's surprise.

Answer (score 0):

From the API getExtendedState() :

```
Gets the state of this frame. The state is represented as a bitwise mask.
NORMAL 
Indicates that no state bits are set.
ICONIFIED
MAXIMIZED_HORIZ
MAXIMIZED_VERT
MAXIMIZED_BOTH 
Concatenates MAXIMIZED_HORIZ and MAXIMIZED_VERT.
```

The logical OR will combine the returned value with the value of JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH

for example if NORMAL was 10110 and MAXIMIZED_BOTH was 01100, ORing the two would yeild 1110

```
Normal  10110
MaxBoth 01100
Result  11110
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR

> A bitwise OR takes two bit patterns of equal length and performs the
>   logical inclusive OR operation on each pair of corresponding bits. The
>   result in each position is 1 if the first bit is 1 or the second bit
>   is 1 or both bits are 1; otherwise, the result is 0. For example:
>
> ```
>    0101 (decimal 5)
> OR 0011 (decimal 3)
>  = 0111 (decimal 7)
> ```

So if getExtendedState() is returning a number made up of binary flags (ie. a bit field)... ORing it (using the pipe operator | ), is simply keeping ALL the existing flags in the object's state and *also* setting the bit/s that correspond to the state JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH.

This is because ORing sets a bit to 1 if it is 1 in either the first operand OR the second operand.

Hope that helps explain it.